# Как уменьшить длительность запроса к БД(mysql) на localhost

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Запросы к БД (mysql 5.5) на localhost'е длиться около 20сек.(имею ввиду сам запрос и вывод его посредством php 5.4.17(самописный движок)),все собрано на apache 2.4. На боевом же сервере все "летает".
Подскажите в чем может быть дело? В настройках Апача или может быть в php?

Да, стоит отметить, что тормозит сборка под Win7, на Ubunte 13.04 на XAMPP из коробки все очень хорошо работает, может и на Windows стоило бы XAMPP развернуть.

Comment: кстати, недавно тоже обновили php и mysql, после чего все стало жутко тормозить... Точно еще не определили в чем проблема.

а так, проверьте настройки кэша, индексирование...

Comment: А можно запрос увидеть?

Comment: Запросы стандартные, типа "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?", результат передается клиенту через AJAX(нативный js). Никаких JOINT'ов или еще чего прочего нет, поэтому то и странно.Может из-за использования всяких JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE и т.п., или чушь несу?

Comment: иногда помогает замена localhost на 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Windows + Apache 2.4 - это мина замедленного действия. Мы потеряли 2 недели, прежде чем выяснили, что 2.4 на windows работает очень нестабильно - временами нормально, потом может начать тормозить, а то и вовсе перестаёт слушать запросы.

Снесли 2.4, поставили старый добрый 2.2. Всё летает.